# CLGeocoder force specific language on iOS8

Tags: ios8, nslocale, clgeocoder

I'm using this method [iOS Force geolocation to return city name in a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310237/ios-force-geolocation-to-return-city-name-in-a-specific-language) to get the cities names on a specific language. It works well on iOS 7.x but using the iOS8 simulator i always receive the data on the user's locale settings.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `CLGeocoder` no longer references the 
`[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];`

There has to be something else that `CLGeocoder` uses to figure out what locale translation to return. It would be really nice if they would just include a parameter for setting the locale like Android does.

Comment: The best option I could find was to check if the returned string is Latin based as demoed in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415570/how-to-determine-if-an-nsstring-is-latin-based). I got away with using the state and country abbreviations so they are in plain English. I ignored the city if the `NSString` from the city returned NO for the following method: `[cityString canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];`